# java Unused Formal parameter: Avoid unused constructor parameters such as 'upper'

Tags: java, sonarqube

We have this application called sonar to analyze code for proper coding practice. One of the violations that it's indicting is :  Unused Formal parameter:  Avoid unused constructor parameters such as 'upper'.

```
 //Private inner class to set the input to a max length.
 public class TextLimiter extends PlainDocument
{
 private int limit;

 public TextLimiter(int limit)
{
    super();
    this.limit = limit;
}

TextLimiter(int limit, boolean upper)
{
    super();
    this.limit = limit;
}

public void insertString(int offset, String str, AttributeSet attr)
        throws BadLocationException
{
    if (str == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if ((getLength() + str.length()) <= limit)
    {
        super.insertString(offset, str, attr);
    }
  }
}
```

I am not exactly sure how to correct this.

Comment: Use the formal parameter? What's `upper` for? You do nothing with it.

Comment: I am not sure.  Howerver if i remove upper i get a duplicate method error.

Comment: Honestly, i got the code from the net where somone wrote a class to limit the amount of text that can be written to a text field.

Comment: @user1158745 Of course you get that. It would duplicate the other constructor. The big question is: 1. What does this parameter mean? 2. Which callers use it, and what do they give for it? What do they expect? 3. Where could it be useful in the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no use for the upper parameter I don't think you should keep it just because it was in the original code. To stop the warning about duplicated code, just remove `TextLimiter(int limit, boolean upper)` and keep `public TextLimiter(int limit)`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing.  I looked at it a few times and was like "WTF" is it doing in the first place.  Then i removed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by making use of that parameter, like this:

```
public TextLimiter(int limit) {
    this(limit, false);
}

TextLimiter(int limit, boolean upper) {
    super();
    if (upper) {
        this.limit = limit;
    } else {
        this.limit = -limit;
    }
}
```

This is just an example of how to use `upper`. It is impossible to decide without knowing the purpose behind your class.